# Random sequence generator algorithm non informative piror distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, sequence-analysis

I want to conduct a Bayesian statistical analysis of a sequence generation phenomenon.

The sequences generated contain elements from a known alphabet.

Working on that, I have tried to define the prior probability distribution of frequencies of each element of the alphabet without any information about the phenomenon except the alphabet. **My intuition is that there is no specific reason that the priors would not be 1/n with n given by the length of the alphabet, because of the "Principle of Insufficient Reason"**. But what would be the shape of the frequency probability distribution?

More generally I assume the question is equivalent to :

If I randomly generate a sequence generator algorithm, that takes as input an alphabet, without any assumptions can I define a prior probability distribution function for the frequency of each element of the alphabet?